# Thin proxy class for hashables

Tags: python, design-patterns, wrapper

I need some kind of thin wrapper object to mark dictionary keys, like:

```
d = {
  Required('name'): str,
  Optional('age'): int,
}
```

And these wrappers should behave like the wrapped object (comparison, hashing, etc):

```
marked = Required('name')
marked == 'name'  #-> True
d[marked] = 'hello'
d['name']  #-> 'hello'
```

With a single additional property: it should remember the added class:

```
isinstance(marked, Required)  #-> True
```

---

I dislike those heavyweight [Proxy Patterns](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) which mimic all special properties and thinking of the following idea instead:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        value_type = type(value)
        Type = type(
            value_type.__name__,  # same name
            (cls, value_type),  # Wrapper + bases
            {})
        Type.__new__ = value_type.__new__  # prevent recursion
        return Type(value)

    # Override method
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Wrapper({})'.format(self)
```

This basically instantiates the type again, but with an additional base, and seems to work:

```
v = 'abc'  # Wrapped value
vt = type(v)  # Wrapped value type
w = Wrapper(v)

assert w == v  # equality
assert isinstance(w, vt)  # type matches
assert isinstance(w, Wrapper)  # and is Wrapper
assert hash(w) == hash(v)  # hash matches (required for dict keys)
```

Can you think of any disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510668/thin-proxy-class-for-hashables#25510718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked, "Can you think of any disadvantages of this approach?" One obvious problem is that this requires you to construct a new class each time the wrapper is called, which potentially ends up wasting a lot of memory. So you would want to cache and reuse these classes.

```
class Wrapper(object):
    # A map from (value type, wrapper class) to wrapped class
    __cache = {}

    def __new__(cls, value):
        value_type = type(value)
        bases = value_type, cls
        try:
            wrapper_class = cls.__cache[bases]
        except KeyError:
            wrapper_class = type(value_type.__name__, bases, {})
            cls.__cache[bases] = wrapper_class
        return wrapper_class(value)
```

Note that this is a rare case where we actually want to use a [private name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) — the idea is to avoid a name clash when wrapping a class that already has a `cache` (or `_cache`, or whatever name we pick) attribute.

I can't help feeling, though, that Martijn Pieters is right in the [Stack Overflow version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25510668/68063): if you just want to proxy a dictionary key, then you just need to proxy the `__eq__` and `__hash__` special methods. Keep it simple!